Keystore file problem
I have a problem: Many years ago i've lost my ethereum keystore file ( mist erased it). And now with help of hexeditor i have restored a part of it. It contains almost all data without: "cipherparams":{"iv": ... part. I have all another parts and password. Can i get "iv": from "ciphertext/any other" part and password" or can i get PrivateKey from any part of keystore file without "cipherparams":{"iv": ... part ? Thx a lot ...

The private key is encrypted with the password using the parameters from cipherparams. The most important part is "iv" which is random data, the rest of the params are selected by the wallet so you could copy from another file.
